# Getting Data from JSON with React gives blank page

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

The purpose of my React one page app is just to render JSON data from another Drupal app. My app shows no error in rendering, but I am only getting a blank page both with Fetch and AXIOS. I have tested the JSON on Postman and also from the Drupal site URL and it works. Please can you tell me where I have gone wrong.

And here is my React mapping component. I am using Fetch in the App.js

```js
import React from 'react'

const Posts = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <center><h1>Articles Post List</h1></center>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <div class="article">
          <div class="article-body">
            <h5 class="article-id">{post.node.Nid}</h5>
            <h6 class="article-title ">{post.node.title}</h6>
            <p class="article-text">{post.node.Body}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};

export default Posts
```

And here is the structure of my JSON feed:

[Drupal json feed screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujpOR.jpg)

Comment: Are you *sure* that `posts` is an array of objects in the structure you want?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post screenshots or code or error messages. Just include the relevant parts as formatted text directly in your question.

Comment: Adding your code fetching data might help. The "Posts" code looks fine

Comment: Code fetch data :
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "node": {
                "Nid": "145",
                "title": "CONTACT",
                "Body": "To contact Auntie Mo Radio write mail@cognin.org\n"
            }
        },
        {
            "node": {
                "Nid": "144",
                "title": "The Fun Bunch Sings - Skip to My Lou",

Comment: Seems like there is no way to post code in comments. Please see the image I earlier posted for the structure. Here it is : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujpOR.jpg